# How to set default layer coordinate system into geographic coordinate systems (-180-180, -90-90)?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis

I want all my global layer to calculate extent in terms of geographic coordinate systems like this:
[image]

For example not to get GRASS errors like `Invalid north field: 7191040N` automagically.
Where one can encounter such problem:
[image]

So how one can to set default layer coordinate system into geographic coordinate system (-180-180, -90-90)?

Comment: Well, to start, you'd need to mark the data with the correct coordinate system, so you could deproject it.

Comment: yep - I want to set the project default to one that grass would love the most (one that is in (-180-180, -90-90) range=) So I wonder how it is called?

Comment: Setting the correct projection on a data source has nothing at all to do with project defaults.

Comment: QGis allows to set project default and force all layers to auto-convert to it=)) so I mainly need the name=))

Comment: No, if the layer has *incorrect* projection properties, it is not possible for project-on-the-fly to operate correctly. This is the most common problem raised in GIS SE.